# Why is there a five second pause at the beginning of every video?

Tags: drivers, nvidia, graphics, video, intel-graphics

Recently, I've started to experience 5-6 seconds delay when starting to watch any video (On Youtube, VLC, Movies Application, etc...)

Also, if I pause a video and wait 5-6 seconds and then hit play, Youtube waits 5 seconds, with loading gif and resumes playing, VLC on the other hand, resumes playing but without sound for 5 seconds, then sound starts to play.

I have Intel graphics card and non-propreitary drivers installed. Also nouveau driver is installed for nvidia.

```
lspci | grep VGA
```

Gives

```
00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation Haswell-ULT Integrated Graphics Controller (rev 0b)
```

Answer (score 0):

This is an old posting from 2011 but I found that it nonetheless helped me with a similar delayed audio problem: https://www.tolaris.com/2011/07/03/solving-the-2-second-sound-delay-with-xbmc-and-hdmi/

To quote the relevant portion:

> Run this in a terminal (or in /etc/rc.local, or ~/.gnomerc, or however
>   you like):
>
> aplay -c2 -r48000 -fS16_LE < /dev/zero &

This plays constant silence with little performance hit (if any) and, at least in my case, solves the audio delay issue.